# Pandas: How to print the groupby values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following data set from `Table_Record`:

```
Seg_ID  Lock_ID  Code
111     100      1
222     121      2
333     341      2
444     100      1
555     100      1
666     341      2
777     554      4
888     332      5
```

I am using the sql query to find the `Seg_IDs` where `Lock_ID` is repeated:

```
Select Code,Lock_ID,Seg_ID from Table_Record group by Code, Lock_ID;

Seg_ID  Lock_ID  Code
111     100      1
444     100      1
555     100      1
222     121      2
333     341      2
666     341      2
777     554      4
888     332      5
```

How can I achieve the same using Pandas?

```
Excepted O/P from Pandas is:
```

eg.

```
Seg_ID (111,444,555) has Lock_id (1).
Seg_ID (222,333,666) has Lock_ID (2).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get all `codes` by filtering only [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) values and then filter original `DaatFrame` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
codes = df.loc[df.duplicated(['Lock_ID']), 'Code'].unique()

df1 = df[df['Code'].isin(codes)]
print (df1)
   Seg_ID  Lock_ID  Code
0     111      100     1
1     222      121     2
2     333      341     2
3     444      100     1
4     555      100     1
5     666      341     2
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `f-string`s:

```
for k, v in df1.groupby(['Code'])['Seg_ID']:
    print (f'Seg_ID {tuple(v)} has Code ({k})')

Seg_ID (111, 444, 555) has Code (1)
Seg_ID (222, 333, 666) has Code (2)
```

If want output like `DataFrame` use `apply` with `tuple`:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Code'])['Seg_ID'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
print (df2)
   Code           Seg_ID
0     1  (111, 444, 555)
1     2  (222, 333, 666)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). As I could understand from your code, you'd want:

```
 grouped= df.groupby(['Code']['LockId'])
```